# In Twilio, How can I use Whatsapp buttons or list option in 24hour session without using message templates

Tags: java, twilio, whatsapp

In Twilio, How can I use Whatsapp buttons or list option in 24hour session without using message templates?

This is the exact [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages) that I am planning to implement. In this page, it doesn't mandate that I have to have message templates to implement interactive messaging.

But, in Twilio, I read it as messaging template is mandatory for Button/Quick Reply use cases in Twilio [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons?code-sample=code-send-a-whatsapp-message-with-buttons&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=8.x#creating-templates-with-buttons)

Is it possible to implement interactive messaging as described in [whatsapp documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages), with list options or buttons without the message templates using Twilio Java SDK? If Yes, please throw some light on the usage or share links of any such examples or any references.

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently, as you have read, the [Twilio API for WhatsApp only supports adding buttons to messages via templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).